# How to query based on condition in dynamo db table?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have Table with following items where p_id is Primary partition key and p_type (String) is a Primary sort key.

```
p_id    p_type    address    name       phone
1221    Men
```

I want to write query in node js function with this condition: "select all where p_type ="men" and address.area="abc".

my address item is a map and it looks like this:

```
"address": {
    "M": {
      "area": {
        "S": "abc"
      },
      "city": {
        "S": "Bengaluru"
      },
}
```

How to achieve this. do i have to create global secondary index?if yes how to create it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot use `Query` based on the sort key.
>
> `Query` work when you create `GSI` to `p_type`.

**Another solution is**

> You can use `scan` operator instead of `query`